# Fix the Firebase Tableview data display

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I am setting up a `UITableView` to display the database content on my App.
unfortunately the information is not displaying and its crashing the application.

the error given is:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

[image]

```
    typealias ItemInfo = (Titulo: String, Description: String, Rating: String, photo: String, email: String, location: String, telefone: String, Linkdetalhes: String)

  fileprivate var items: [ItemInfo]! = [( "Titulo","Description","Rating","photo","email","location","telefone", "Linkdetalhes")]


   (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).fireBaseRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            let dictRoot = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
            let dictAliances = dictRoot["Eventos"] as? [String: AnyObject] ?? [:]
            for key in Array(dictAliances.keys) {
                let alianceDic = dictAliances[key]
                self.items.append(( alianceDic!["Title"] as! String, alianceDic!["photo"] as! String, alianceDic!["Description"] as! String, alianceDic!["Rating"] as! String, alianceDic!["email"] as! String, alianceDic!["location"] as! String, alianceDic!["telefone"] as! String, alianceDic!["Linkdetalhes"] as! String))

                self.tableView?.reloadData()
            }
            print(dictAliances)
        })
```

Comment: Add the code you've tried so far.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7hsd.png

Comment: Check whether `tableView` outlet is connected.

Comment: they are connected

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code `as! String` to `as? String`. See the following. ignore force unwrapping. It may be found nill value or missing key value in a dictionary.

```
self.items.append(( alianceDic!["Title"] as? String, alianceDic!["photo"] as? String, alianceDic!["Description"] as? String, alianceDic!["Rating"] as? String, alianceDic!["email"] as? String, alianceDic!["location"] as? String, alianceDic!["telefone"] as? String, alianceDic!["Linkdetalhes"] as? String))
```

Comment: check once dictionary data, is it proper?

Comment: init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject], key: String) {
        self.key = key
        self.Title = dictionary["Title"] as! String
        self.Description = dictionary["Description"] as! String
        self.photo = dictionary["photo"] as! String
        self.Rating = dictionary["Rating"] as! String
        self.email = dictionary["email"] as! String
        self.location = dictionary["location"] as! String
        self.telefone = dictionary["telefone"] as! String
        self.linkdetalhes = dictionary["linkdetalhes"] as! String
    }